# How do I switch stylesheets with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I designed a multicolored template and now I want to change only the "CSS" file when clicking on the color icon, anyone can help me please?

This is my code but it is not working good, just change the color for one time only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.silver").click(function() {
    $("a.silver").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/silver/css/template.css"/>');
  });

  $("a.red").click(function() {
    $("a.red").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.css"/>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't do it this way. Toggle classes instead.

Comment: @MattBall I don't know why, that's why I asked.   I would have gone for swapping the style sheet.  Just changing the class sounds wrong to me - it wouldn't scale well.

Answer (score 3):

So, as some comments said, your best bet is to toggle CSS Classes. But if you're changing the whole page style, then swapping stylesheets seems like a fine idea to me. But it's unnecessary for you to "regenerate" the elements each time you want to swap stylesheets. you're probably better off just detaching them from the DOM as necessary. So something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sheets = { //a map of sheets. Simply add sheets to this to add more themes (and create appropriate links to them)
        silver: $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/silver/css/template.css"/>'),
        red: $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.css"/>')
    };

    var currentSheet = sheets.red.appendTo($("head")); //attach default sheet

    $("a.swapStyle").click(function () {
         currentSheet.detach(); //remove the current sheet
         currentSheet = (sheets[$(this).attr("data-theme")]).appendTo($("head")); //attach a new sheet and set the currentSheet variable to remember it.
    });
});
```

You'll need to change your links to something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="swapStyle" data-theme="red">Change to red theme</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="swapStyle" data-theme="silver">Change to silver theme</a>
```

Comment: This is the closest to how my approach would look, and this would scale very well for more than two colour schemes.  But I'd still like to know why people are arguing for toggling classes.  Classes aren't supposed to represent specific colours, etc.  Classes should stay constant, and the _styling_ of those classes should change.

Comment: On the flip side, just using `.detach()` to remove the current sheet will still leave it hanging around in memory...

Comment: @Alnitak I think they're talking about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ztVw9/

Comment: Thanks guys, since I'm still a beginner using JQuery , all what you said is very useful for me... All those ways change the color but when I refresh the page or navigate to another page it returns back to the default style sheet..

Comment: @Alnitak I used detach because it saves some processing time when switching back to a previous theme at the expense of some memory. It's a trade-off that the developer can choose to ignore if they want.

Comment: @SabryMuhamadSabry you can't have everything!  If you want to _remember_ which sheet it had you need to store some state somewhere.

Comment: @SabryMuhamadSabry If you want to retain the theme when switching pages, you'll need to use a cookie. You can modify my code to do this by having `currentSheet` hold the key for the sheet instead of the sheet itself, then save `currentSheet` to a cookie when it changes and revert from the cookie when the page loads.

Comment: @Pete IMHO that example you linked to is a bloody stupid way to swap themes.  It keeps every theme in memory all of the time and makes CSS parsing and maintenance horrendous.

Comment: @SabryMuhamadSabry Here's a version of my class-based swapper that stores the cookie (external stylesheets are a pain in JSFiddle, but the concept is the same for the stylesheet swapping). http://jsfiddle.net/ghesJ/  -- Note that I am using the jQuery cookie plug-in from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to make cookie setting/getting easier. (Edit: just noticed my cookie example doesn't work in Safari. Probably because of JSFiddle. It will work when not wrapped in JSFiddle).

Comment: @Alnitak I totally agree. That's why I posted a solution using stylesheet swapping instead. :-) I was just responding to your request for an example of the class-based switching people were talking about. As I note at the start of my answer, if you're making lots of changes between themes, it's better (in my opinion) to swap stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

Css link has to be added to the head

```
             $(document).ready(function() {
               //load silver automatically in ready

                 $("a.silver").click(function() {
                         $('head > link').last().remove();   //removes red and adds silver
                         $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
                   });

                 $("a.red").click(function() {
                        $('head > link').last().remove();  //remove silver - adds red
                        .append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/silver/css/template.css"/>');
                          });
                    });
             });
```

the actual stylesheets in my jQuery aren't correct

Comment: @ScottSelby as written the "silver" stylesheet will _augment_ (and/or overwrite) the original, not replace it.  This would give the page renderer more work to do.

Comment: @Alnitak - .toggleClass is the preferred way to change styling dynamically - he specifically wants to 'add or remove style sheets'

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, it is probably best practice to toggle css styles rather than files but if toggling files is necessary, try:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.silver').click(function (){
       $('link[href="css/template.css"]').attr('href','themes/silver/css/template.css');
    });
    $('a.red').click(function (){
       $('link[href="themes/silver/css/template.css"]').attr('href','css/template.css');
    });
});
```

In this solution, you must also define the style in the head as you normally would...

Comment: @SabryMuhamadSabry IMHO, Pete's answer is much better.

Comment: @Alnitak He provided support for not regenerating the entire style tag but you have not provided any defense why this answer is not valid

Comment: @r0m4n I didn't say this answer is invalid, I said that Pete's is much better.  Specifically his answer will trivially scale to more than two alternate themes.  Yours won't.

Comment: That was not his question "How do I switch stylesheets with jQuery?"  In his current answer, no stylesheet would even be loaded on disabled js

Comment: OH REALLY? I tried "r0m4n" code with more than 2 themes and it works! ... and I still prefer "r0m4n" code as I write less :)